# Will Ractive.js append or rebuild all when I append to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ractivejs

Template

```
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>

    {{#each items:num}}
    <li>#{{num}} {{items[num]}}</li>
    {{/each}}

</script>
```

JS

```
<script>
  window.r = new Ractive({
    // The `el` option can be a node, an ID, or a CSS selector.
    el: '.reactivejs',

    // We could pass in a string, but for the sake of convenience
    // we're passing the ID of the <script> tag above.
    template: '#template',

    // Here, we're passing in some initial data
    data: {name: 'world',items:["Food","Tools","Human"]}
  });
</script>
```

If I append to array like this:

```
r.get("items").push("Somthing")
```

How ractivejs render the appended element ? rebuild all or just append a new dom element ? This is important because this array may contain thousands element.Rebuild all is very slow, and this array will update quickly.

Comment: Why u dont just test it?

Comment: Sorry for my lazy, just want to sleep now.

Comment: A new template would need to be re-rendered,  but append, i guess no, but it better be test it

Comment: I test with `for(j=0;j < 10; j ++){var start = moment().unix();for(i=0;i < 1000; i ++){r.get("items").push("Woman");}console.log(moment().unix()-start)}`. Seems it's append, but still not sure, with element group up, may browser slow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will append the node. You can that by tagging the nodes (see http://jsfiddle.net/4j6xzbwv/):

```
var length = 10;
var arr = new Array(length);
while(length--){
    arr[length] = 'item' + length;
}

var r = new Ractive({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        list: arr
    }
})

var tags = document.querySelectorAll('p');

length = tags.length;
while(length--){
    tags[length].setAttribute('data-tagged', true);
}

r.push('list', 34);

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('p[data-tagged=true]').length, r.get('list.length'));
```

It also works with splice (http://jsfiddle.net/4j6xzbwv/1/) and checkout [`ractive.merge`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-merge) for shuffle-like operations.

Ractive is also smart about reusing the DOM nodes if you do set a new array. You can see in http://jsfiddle.net/4j6xzbwv/2/ how the DOM nodes are reused by the new array, as only the text node content needs to be updated